# Should "the" precede "word"?

Tags: articles

What is the rule on using articles in front of "word"? For example:

> Please remove the word "judge" from your vocabulary.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Generally you would treat 'word' like any other noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you refer to a specific word, so using a definite article is grammatically correct. It's the same as saying "remove the nail from the board." To exclude the article you would have to change the sentence to be more general, such as "remove judgmental words."